# Encoding issue with é character

Tags: php, utf-8

My file is encoded in UTF-8, all characters work fine it except "**é**"

I have tried several solutions but I always get this character � instead (and only for few words) :

Here is an example of the few option I have tried :

```
$auteur= utf8_decode("Aurélie ABBĀSĀBĀD");  
$commAuteur = mb_convert_encoding($auteur, "HTML-ENTITIES", 'UTF-8');
```

I added utf8_decode to be sure I'm going from ISO-8859-1 to utf-8, then I tried also this :

```
$commAuteur  = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $auteur);
```

I eventually also tried this :

```
 $commAuteur = htmlentities($auteur);
```

None of all these options worked correctly, and I don't understand how some é are displayed normally and others have this issue, im out of solutions any suggestions ?

Comment: is this database-related by any chance?

Comment: You don't need to do anything. Just save your source code file as UTF-8 and `echo` the string. `utf8_decode` converts *from ISO-88591 to UTF-8*, the opposite of what you expect.

Comment: what is the file's encoding also?

Comment: This may help: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: the file is encoded in UTF-8 and I did try not doing anything but it doesn't work that's why i started looking for functions that could solve the issue

Comment: UTF-8 has two modes; one with and one without a BOM (byte order mark) which will make a difference.

Comment: The one i have is without the BOM

Comment: In a nutshell: `$auteur` is ISO-8859 encoded (because of `utf8_decode`), yet the code always seems to treat it as if it is UTF-8 encoded. That's the entire issue. You just need to get rid of all those functions it's calling.

Comment: actually all those functions were placed to test why for some word the é caracter is displayed and for others it's not, when I did just utf8_decode i noticed that the é is translated to "?" for some words and for others to  � how is that possible ?

Comment: What exactly is the difference between *some of those words and others*? Are they in different files? Do they come from different sources (e.g. database)?

Comment: That's my problem they are in the same array and they come from the same database here is an example : Aurélie becomes : Aur� lie and jérémy becomes j?r?my

Comment: Then you need to go into more detail here. With encoding the details matter a lot; it's a big difference asking about a string literal in a file and data from a database. General hint: use `echo bin2hex($str)` to *see* what bytes your string actually consists of, which allows you to identify what *encoding* it's actually in, which allows you to debug what's going on.

Comment: when I tried bin2hex($str) i got **c3a9** for the é of jérémy et **3f6c** for the é of Aurélie so the é is not translated in the same way